# Jenkins Installation on Ubuntu 14 - jenkins service is not running

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Hey guys I installed jenkins on ubuntu. then check the jenkins service and it is not working. I tried to run jenkins with

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=                                                                  -1
```

there is my log file. How can I fix this ?

Thanks for help

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war


Sep 28, 2017 1:50:41 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
**WARNING**: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war


Sep 28, 2017 1:50:42 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setConte                                                                  xtPath
**WARNING**: Empty contextPath

Sep 28, 2017 1:50:49 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStop
INFO: Stopped ServerConnector@eadd4fb{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}

Sep 28, 2017 1:50:49 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper stopScavenging
INFO: Stopped scavenging

Sep 28, 2017 1:50:49 AM hudson.WebAppMain contextDestroyed
INFO: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason


Sep 28, 2017 1:50:49 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStop
INFO: Stopped w.@72bc6553{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/var/cache/jenkins/war}

**SEVERE**: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:294)
        at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop any other tomcat running at port 8080. Maybe try to find other processes by executing

> ps aux | grep java

and kill them, then restart Jenkins